# Subversion client in the Solaris box?

Tags: svn, centos, solaris

We are using CentOS and a Solaris box. In CentOS, I am able to use the SVN command-line.
But in Solaris, if I try to use SVN command-line, I am getting a `command not found` error. How do I install the SVN client on Solaris, so that I can access the command-line for a normal user? Can anyone help me with the installation?

Comment: http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#solaris

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Solaris 11 or later, install it from the Solaris package repository, `sudo pkg install developer/versioning/subversion`.

On Solaris 10 and older, there is no system package repository and a much older packaging system, with fewer packages available from the OS itself, so you'll need to either build it from sources or find a package to download from another repository such as [OpenCSW.org](https://www.opencsw.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and in addition I did not have root privileges.

I installed SVNKit from http://svnkit.com/, a Java based SVN client that has a command line included. You only need a JVM (also installable without being root).